# Jquery hide/show div from select box is not working, I can't figure out why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following jQuery:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".search_type").hide();
        $("#select_search").change(function () {
            $('#' + $(this).val()).toggle();
        });
    });
</script>
<select id="select_search">
      <option value="1">
      <option value="2">
      <option value="3">
 </select>
 <div id="1" class="search_type">Some Text</div>
 <div id="2" class="search_type">Some Text</div>
 <div id="3"class="search_type">Some Text</div>
enter code here
```

Currently I have it display the corresponding div based on select box change, however, this does not remove it if the select box is changed again.

Is there an if(($this):not.val()).....Something something hide? Sorry, I'm new to JS / jQuery, and am really struggling here.

Comment: please share the related html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to hide the previously displayed element, one easy way to sue hide all the `search_type` elements again the the change handler then show current element

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var $stypes = $(".search_type").hide();
    $("#select_search").change(function () {
        $stypes.hide();
        $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
    }).change();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/RuE6a/)

Answer (score 0):

no but you can do it like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".search_type").hide();
    $("#select_search").change(function() {
        $(".search_type").hide();
        $("#" + $(this).val()).show();
    });
});
```

this will hide all elements with the class `search_type` then show the selection.

you can also make a placeholder variable, like so:

```
var showing;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".search_type").hide();
    $("#select_search").change(function() {
        if (showing) {showing.hide();}
        showing = $("#" + $(this).val());
        showing.show();
    });
});
```

Comment: Your "placeholder variable" example won't work, the line with _showing.hide()_ will give an error about _showing_ being undefined and stop before it shows the selected item. (Also it would be neater to put the _var showing_ declaration inside the document ready handler, no need to make it global.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unclear on your question, but as best I can tell you want to display one DIV that corresponds to the user's choice from a select box.  If the user selects a differnt option, you want to hide the previously show box, correct?

I think this sample will help you: http://jsfiddle.net/HaMQr/

There is a `$.not( object )` method which will take action on any matching object which is NOT the one you provide.  See the code below:

```
$("#select_search").change(function () {
    var activeBox = $('#' + $(this).val());
    activeBox.show();

    $('div').not(activeBox).hide();                
 });
```